# Qt: init-repository aborts with "fatal: Needed a single revision"

Tags: c++, git, qt, qt5

I'm trying to build revision 5.9 of Qt5 from git sources but updating the submodules fails:

```
git clone https://github.com/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5
git checkout 5.9
./init-repository
...
... lots of submodules being updated successfully
...

fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current revision in submodule path 'qtnetworkauth'
git submodule update --force --no-fetch exited with status 256 at ./init-repository line 198.
    Qt::InitRepository::exe(Qt::InitRepository=HASH(0x1fa94b0), "git", "submodule", "update", "--force", "--no-fetch") called at ./init-repository line 429
    Qt::InitRepository::git_clone_all_submodules(Qt::InitRepository=HASH(0x1fa94b0), "qt/qt5", 0, "preview", "essential", "addon", "deprecated") called at ./init-repository line 644
    Qt::InitRepository::run(Qt::InitRepository=HASH(0x1fa94b0)) called at ./init-repository line 655
```

So it looks like `qtnetworkauth` is somehow mis-configured but I don't know how to solve it.
I tried to remove the `qtnetworkauth` module by deleting references inside `.gitmodules`, `qtdoc` and the folder itself but then other modules fail.

Strangely - when I run `./init-repository -f` after removing and adding references to `qtnetworkauth` I can see it being checked out, but the submodules folder is still empty:

```
...
+ git clone --no-checkout https://github.com/qt/qtnetworkauth qtnetworkauth
Cloning into 'qtnetworkauth'...
remote: Counting objects: 283, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
remote: Total 283 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 269
Receiving objects: 100% (283/283), 200.12 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (139/139), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
+ git config commit.template /home/frans/_HOME/0000_android_dev/qt5/.commit-template
+ git config remote.gerrit.url ssh://codereview.qt-project.org/qt/qtnetworkauth
...
```

What can I have done wrong? Or if it's a Qt bug - how can I workaround it?

Answer (score 1):

You're changing branches before actually getting all the repositories. That probably breaks something in the `./init-repository` script.

I've checked that this sequence works:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
cd qt5/
./init-repository
git checkout 5.9
git submodule update
```

Comment: Well that's funny - although changing the order of my commands didn't have an effect you helped me anyway. The problem seems to be the github clone I've used. Cloning from `code.qt.io` solves my problem, even though both clones are identical (except the remotes). Change your answer and I'll accept it.